# C++: how to get the path of a variable?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

I would like to know whether it's possible to get (at runtime) a unique name for each variable in a C++ program.
For example, if in the main I declare

```
MyClass A;
```

and in MyClass I declare

```
int I;
```

I'd like a magic forumla that returns something like "main/A/I".

Does something like this exists?

Thank you!

---

The purpose of this is keeping track of variable assignments.
I wrote a class that I use as wrapper for standard data type. The constructor for this class accepts a string, to identify each variable.

The problem occurrs when I have a variable declared in a class, and multiple instantiations of this class.
I.e.

```
class MyClass {
...
MyInt data ("variable_name"); // MyInt is the wrapper for int
... 
};

...

int main () {
...
MyClass a;
MyClass b;
...
}
```

Statically initializing the name of data will make it impossible to dintinguish between a.data and b.data.
As someone suggested, I could use maybe use the memory address as an ID, but how will it be possible to map the address to a human readable path?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: What's the point of this?

Comment: No, something like this doesn't exist (in the core language).

Comment: You might be able to derive something close to what you want if debugging symbols are available. You can look at the implementation of [`objdump`](http://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/src/gnu/usr.bin/binutils-2.17/binutils/objdump.c) to see how to parse debugging information. You can search about Reflection in C++ to see what other approaches have been attempted.

Comment: The thing is, what you actually think of as "variables" need not exist at all in the actual program. Compilers are allowed to optimize anything away as long as the program behaves "as if" the optimizations had not been performed.

Comment: You could write a templated function which outputs the name of the static type, the name of the dynamic type (for poylorphic types) and the address of the object. But what we see as variables in our source might have different names (think about references) and needs no name at all at runtime. But different objects have different addresses.

Comment: I improved my question with more details about the problem I would like to solve

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're doing some additional work (when declaring data structures), in general this is not possible in C++. There's no such data stored anywhere in the program.

And indeed, as one of commenters mentioned, in some cases, in platform-specific way IF you have debug data (like pdb in windows), you may be able to do that as debuggers do.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not in the sense you're describing. What it sounds you want is to have a variable identified by its entire inheritance hierarchy, which is what reference sites are for and having this information in a program would just add significance performance issues.

If you just want a unique identifier to make every variable identifiable and global in your program, seriously rethink this.  It's very bad design not to mention practice and will lead to many, many, an annoying bug.

However, this might be what you're asking:

"Can I list my variable class structure of a particular program X?"

You can. But it might be more work than you want, C++ doesn't have such a thing built in, however it might exist somewhere, but if it does I don't know.  To do this you can make a parser parse your code into a parse tree and traverse the tree using a visitor pattern, printing out each variable as it gets to it with the parent leaves appended to it.  This is information you can see through a debugger (not the variables but every compiler parses and constructs a parse tree then executes on it), it's what the debugger saves as it builds through runtime so you can "walk-back" through it, you're actually walking back through your programs parse tree.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want to achieve, according to my knowledge there is no C++ function which will give you the details, you have to write the functionality on your own, I am giving some code snippet, don't know whether it will help:

```
class MyClass
{
        public:
        MyClass(int z) : i(z)
        {
        }
        const char* getType()
        {
            return typeid(i).name();
        }
    private:
        int i;
};

class MyClassDerived:public MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClassDerived(int k):MyClass(k)
        {        
        }
};

int main()
{
   MyClass *m = new MyClass(10);
   cout<< typeid(*m).name() << "/" << m->getType()<< endl;

   MyClassDerived *m1 = new MyClassDerived(20);
   cout<< typeid(*m1).name() << "/" << m1->getType();
   return 0;
}
```

`
The out put will be:

7 MyClass/i
14 MyClassDerived/i

Let me know if it solves your issue.